# msvcr100 and msvcrt

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, dll, msvcrt

I noticed that DLL compiled with the old VC6 (**msvcrt.dll**) still runnable and "callable" even into a DLL (or a program) that is linked against **msvcr100.dll**

Very convenient, but do you just think it's a good idea to have both runtimes at the same time in a process ?

Comment: Right, it is not a good idea.  It is however not instant death if the DLL exports are properly designed, not exposing any C++ objects or pointers that need to be released.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it's not exactly good idea to combine multiple C runtimes in one process, on Windows, there is often no way around it. It should work without any problems as long as you don't pass structures implemented by CRT's between parts using separate CRT implementations (most common case: FILE*), at least in C. with C++, things get slightly more complex with different exception handling models and by virtue of C++ being C++.