# How can I reduce potential issues from conflicting MSVCRT's?

Tags: c++, msvcrt

I have a Visual Studio 2010 C++ application with a few 3rd-party libraries that include the Winsock2 header, which drags in MSVCRT.dll when linking with /MD.  I have chosen to recompile these 3rd-party libraries (with VS2010) in order to ***"push down the stack"*** this dependency on MSVCRT.dll and thereby reduce the chance of any [potential problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456271/msvcr100-and-msvcrt) caused by the incompatibility between this and the application's linking with MSVCR100.dll.

1. Is ***this*** generally accurate, i.e. does it reduce the chance of application crash from CRT library mismatches?  I would think that the further down a dependency is pushed, the better chance to isolate potential conflicts between API module and client.
2. More specifically, does the Winsock2 API expose any dangers when exposed to module using a CRT of a different version (i.e. the re-compiled 3rd-party libraries in my example)?  Or can I assume that the application is safe and the 3rd-party libraries will behave properly?